# Detect a color of a sprite

Tags: android, colors, libgdx

I added two sprites. These sprites change their color randomly. Now I want to detect which color a sprite has. Is there any method or posibility for doing that?

I created a sprite sheet which contains ten sprites with different colors. In fact I don't change the color but the region of the sprite sheet. This has the same effect.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? How do they change color?

Comment: I didn´t try anything yet because I don´t know how to do it. The color changes by setting a new region on a sprite sheet. I have ten sprites with different colors on this sheet.

Comment: At a certain time, you are setting a color. Therefore - at that time - you know that color.

Comment: Yup. If you can't tell us how you change the color, I am going to vote to close this question as too broad. The answer depends on how the color is set

Comment: As I said before, I created a sprite sheet which contains ten sprites with different colors. In fact, I don't change the color but the region of the sprite sheet. This has the same effect.

Comment: @user8340536 **Still you set it. You change it somehow, so you need to know which sprite is active.**

Comment: I can only see it on the screen because I change the regions randomly with a timer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get all the sprite(10) in a arrayMap. And get the color value or you can say current sprite, Using this key get map value when you are setting the color or sprite.

```
ArrayMap<Sprite, String> arrayMap=new ArrayMap<Sprite, String>();
        arrayMap.put(sprite1, "Red");
        arrayMap.put(sprite2, "Yellow");
        arrayMap.put(sprite3, "Black");
        arrayMap.put(sprite4, "Pink");
        arrayMap.put(sprite5, "Color1");
        arrayMap.put(sprite6, "Color2");
        arrayMap.put(sprite7, "Color3");
        arrayMap.put(sprite8, "Color4");
        arrayMap.put(sprite9, "Color5");
        arrayMap.put(sprite10, "Color6");
```

Comment: Could you please explain or show me how to make an ArrayMap and how to compare them

Comment: You got it? or need more clarification.

Comment: I think I got it. Thank you!